# Segmentation fault on getline while parsing a file

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm making a very simple file parser, in CSV style. The compilation runs smoothly, and when I run it, I'm having a segfault (core dumped). The only printed line is the one telling "Done" to say that the file succesfully opened. So my guess is that the Segfault happened during `while(getline(myfile, line))`.

Here's my code (`parser.cpp`):

```
#include "parser.h"

vector<string> str_explode(string const & s, char delim)
{
    vector<string> result;
    istringstream iss(s);

    for (string token; getline(iss, token, delim); )
    {
        result.push_back(move(token));
    }
    return result;
}

vector<vector<string>> getTokensFromFile(string fileName)
{
    bool verbose = true;
    if(verbose)
        cout << "Entering getTokensFromFile(" << fileName << ")" << endl ;
    /* declaring what we'll need :
     * string line -> the line beeing parsed
     * ifstream myfile -> the file that name has been given as parameter
     * vector <vector <string> > tokens -> the return value
     * 
     * Putting all line into tokens
     */

    string line;
    ifstream myfile(fileName);
    vector< vector<string> > tokens;
    if(verbose)
        cout << "Opening file " << fileName << " ... ";
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        if(verbose)
            cout << "Done !" << endl;
        while (getline (myfile,line))
        {
            if(verbose)
                cout << "Parsing line '" << line << "'. ";
            // If line is blank or start with # (comment)
            // then we don't parse it
            if((line.length() == 0) || (line.at(0) == '#'))
            {
                if(verbose)
                    cout << "Empty or comment, passing.";
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                vector <string> tmptokens;
                if(verbose)
                    cout << "Adding token " << tmptokens[0] << " and its values.";
                tokens.push_back(tmptokens);
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file " << fileName << endl;
        throw exception();
    }
    if(verbose)
        cout << "Exiting getTokensFromFile(" << fileName << ")" << endl;
    return tokens;
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "parser.h"

int main()
{
    getTokensFromFile("testfile.csv");
    return 0;
}
```

And my `testfile.csv`

```
version;1.3
###### SPECIE ######
SpecieID;Value1
VariantID;Value2
####################

##### IDENTITY #####
Name;Value3
DOName;Value4
####################
```

All files are in the same folder.

Do you have any clue why I'm having this segfault?

Thanks

Comment: `cout << "Adding token " << tmptokens[0] << " and its values.";` -- `tmptokens` is empty, thus there is no `tmptokens[0]`.

Comment: Thanks, my (stupid) mistake.

Comment: Undefined behavior.  Accessing an element out-of-bounds does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one obvious error, where you are accessing a vector's element out-of-bounds.  Accessing an out-of-bounds element is undefined behavior.

```
   else
   {
       vector <string> tmptokens;
       if(verbose)
           cout << "Adding token " << tmptokens[0] << " and its values.";
       tokens.push_back(tmptokens);
   }
```

Since `tmptokens` is empty, there is no `tmptokens[0]`.

If the vector is empty, you could have done this:

```
   else
   {
       if(verbose)
           cout << "Adding new token and its values.";
       tokens.push_back({});
   }
```

There is no need to manually create an empty vector starting with C++11.